# Strategies for Custom Array Functionality in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I find myself often struggling with finding a solution to various array arrangement problems in PHP that fall outside of solutions that I have implemented before.

Currently, I am starting with this array:

```
$tags = array(
            array('tag_id' => 1, 'tag_name' => 'Hello', 'album_id => 1'),
            array('tag_id' => 1, 'tag_name' => 'Hello', 'album_id => 2'),
            array('tag_id' => 2, 'tag_name' => 'World', 'album_id => 1'),
            array('tag_id' => 2, 'tag_name' => 'World', 'album_id => 2'),
            array('tag_id' => 3, 'tag_name' => 'Again', 'album_id => 3')
        );
```

And want to organize it as such:

```
$organized_tags = array(

            array('tag_id' => 1, 'tag_name' => 'Hello', 'album_ids' => array(1,2)),
            array('tag_id' => 2, 'tag_name' => 'World', 'album_ids' => array(1,2)),
            array('tag_id' => 3, 'tag_name' => 'Again', 'album_ids' => array(3))
        );
```

a) what would be the best strategy for solving this kind of problem?
b) how to think about solving generic array problems that come up in the future?

Comment: While this is a terribly broad topic, I'm seeing these *How to reformat my array?* questions constantly. At least this one is trying to be generic, +1 for that. I hope it may stand as a sort of generic canonical Q&A for future visitors and reduce the number of repeated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might take a leaf from the book of CakePHP in representing model data as arrays.

With this, you would have a Tag model, and an Album model.  From the data give, the Tag model looks like

```
['Tag' => ['tag_id' => 1, 'tag_name' => 'Hello']]
```

And, for the moment, the Album only has the id

```
['Album' => ['album_id' => 1']]
```

To represent the organized structure:

```
[
    0 => [
        'Tag' => ['tag_id' => 1, 'tag_name' => 'Hello'],
        'Album' => [
            0 => ['album_id' => 1],
            1 => ['album_id' => 2]
        ],
    1 => [
        'Tag' => ['tag_id' => 2, 'tag_name' => 'World'],
        'Album' => [
            0 => ['album_id' => 1],
            1 => ['album_id' => 2]
        ],
    2 => [
        'Tag' => ['tag_id' => 3, 'tag_name' => 'Again'],
        'Album' => [
            0 => ['album_id' => 3]
        ]
]
```

However, this isn't what you've asked for.

To change `$tags` to `$organized_tags`, I'd do a `Tag` model class that takes the `$tags` structure, iterates through it, and builds the second structure.

```
public function toOrganizedTags($tags) {
    $organizedTags = [];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if (!isset($organizedTags[$tag['tag_id']]) {
            // make sure an entry exists. We assume that tag_name does not change between similar tag_id entries.
            $organizedTags[$tag['tag_id']] = [
                'tag_id' => $tag['tag_id'], 
                'tag_name' => $tag['tag_name'],
                'album_ids' => []
            ];
        }
        $organizedTags[$tag['tag_id']]['album_ids'][] = $tag['album_id'];
    }
    // use array_values to strip the indexed keys
    return array_values($organizedTags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The super naïve approach:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($result as $resultItem) {
        if ($item['tag_id'] == $resultItem['tag_id']) {
            $resultItem['album_ids'][] = $item['album_id'];
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $result = $item + ['album_ids' => (array)$item['album_id']];
}
```

I.e., you just loop over your array and in each iteration also over a result array to see where the item fits in. It's pretty trivial.

Often the more optimised solution is to index your result array by the attribute you're trying to group on:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['album_id']])) {
        $result[$item['album_id']] = $item + ['album_ids' => (array)$item['album_id']];
    } else {
        $result[$item['album_id']]['album_ids'][] = $item['album_id']
    }
}
```